# How can I view the history of inserts to a table?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to see the history or any other information of insertions into a specific table of an SQL Server database?

Comment: Which version of the SQL server?

Comment: The database is running on 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are recording this information somewhere using a trigger, you would need some way of looking at the information in the transaction log. There are commercial tools like Lumigent for this.

Comment: Is the transaction log you're referring to the same as the one accessed by running DBCC log ( {Table}, type=[1|2|3|4])?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trigger

Create a trigger on the table watching for inserts, updates, and deletes).  The trigger would insert into another table (a history table).

This adds extra overhead, though, so I wouldn't do this on a really heavily updated table.

Look at [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210608144836/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/091901-1.shtml) for an example of how this is done.

[This page](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/01/15/codegen-to-create-fixed-audit-trail-triggers.aspx) has some code that generates the audit trail code for you.

[Here is another SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349524/sql-server-history-table-populate-through-sp-or-trigger) about doing this using triggers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use the new Change Data Capture feature. This saves you from having to write triggers on all your tables.

Answer (score 2):

For 2005 use triggers, for 2008 you can use the **[change data capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using a trigger, you could do something like add a column named "InsertedDate" and record the current date there.  This would require you do your insertions through a stored procedure though.

Comment: That would not require a stored proc. If you do this the best bet is to use a constraint to always put in the current date.